# ld can't find a library

Tags: g++, ld

Here is a Makefile:

```
all: main

bar.cxx:
  echo "void bar(){}" > bar.cxx

foo.cxx:
  echo "void bar();" > foo.cxx
  echo "void foo(){ bar(); }" >> foo.cxx

main.cxx:
  echo "void foo();" > main.cxx
  echo "int main(){ foo(); }" >> main.cxx

%.o: %.cxx
  g++ -c -fPIC $<

libbar.so: bar.o
  g++ -shared -o libbar.so bar.o

libfoo.so: foo.o libbar.so
  g++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -L. -Wl,-rpath,\$$ORIGIN/. -lbar

main: main.o libfoo.so
  g++ -o $@ main.o -L. $(PWD)/libfoo.so

clean:
  rm -rf *.so *.o *.cxx main
```

which fails like this on `Ubuntu 14.04`:

```
$ make
echo "void foo();" > main.cxx
echo "int main(){ foo(); }" >> main.cxx
g++ -c -fPIC main.cxx
echo "void bar();" > foo.cxx
echo "void foo(){ bar(); }" >> foo.cxx
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cxx
echo "void bar(){}" > bar.cxx
g++ -c -fPIC bar.cxx
g++ -shared -o libbar.so bar.o
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -L. -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/. -lbar
g++ -o main main.o -L. /media/david/data/tmp/origin/libfoo.so
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libbar.so, needed by /media/david/data/tmp/origin/libfoo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/media/david/data/tmp/origin/libfoo.so: undefined reference to `bar()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

`RPATH` is set relative:

```
$ objdump -p libfoo.so | grep RPATH
  RPATH                $ORIGIN/.
```

`ldd` print the correct path to `libbar.so`:

```
ldd libfoo.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe3f1c8000)
    libbar.so => /media/david/data/tmp/origin/././libbar.so (0x00007f83c29ff000)
```

I have some questions, maybe in wrong order or redundant:

0) Why `ld` can't find `libbar.so`?

1) Why do I need to add `-Wl,rpath,$(PWD)` like below, while `libfoo.so` already contains the `rpath`?

```
main: main.o libfoo.so
  g++ -o $@ main.o -L. -Wl,-rpath,$(PWD) $(PWD)/libfoo.so
```

2) `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. make` solve the problem, but why? I was thinking the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was used only at execution.

3) Why does `-L.` has no effect?

Comment: GNU ld won't look into RPATH of a shared object to find another shared object. The R there stands for *runtime*. It is there for the runtime linker.

Comment: so why -Wl,rpath,$(PWD) do have an effect, and why -L. not?

Comment: Because it is specified to work this slightly confusing way in the documentation. The option both records RPATH in the output object, and tells LD where to find dependencies. If you need only the latter, use -rpath-link.

Comment: That's clear, thanks for the explanation! I was looking here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html but `man ld` on my machine has much more informations